# How to block a thread until another thread gets a server response in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronous

I am working on a library where you can create a server with a name:

```
UtilityServer server = new UtilityServer("TestServer1", 3500);
```

You can also create a client with a name:

```
UtilityClient client = new UtilityClient("TestClient1");
```

The server creates a socket on the local computer with the port you choose. When the server is running, the client can connect via:

```
client.Connect(ServerIP, 3500);
```

Everything works fine when I do it event-based with for example:

```
client.UserNamesArrived += OnUserNamesArrived;
client.RequestUserNames();

private void OnUserNamesArrived(ReadOnlyCollection<string> userNames)
{
    // Do something with userNames
}
```

But when I try to create a blocking method in my library for example:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetUserNames()
{
    // Request userNames from server
    // Wait until server sent us userNames
    // return userNames
}

// Running on seperate thread, gets messages that server sents to client
ReceiveMessages()
{
    while(_isConnected)
    {
    // Waits until message is received (_strReader.ReadLine())
    // Looks what message contains (Can also be other things then userNames)
    // Gets collection of userNames when message contains it (Working)
    // Triggers event 'UserNamesArrived' with userNames as argument
    }
}
```

I don't know how.

Now here is my question, how do I wait in my `GetUserNames-Thread` until my `ReceiveMessages-Thread` gets the collection of `userNames` and how can I return them?

There are similar Methods in the .Net-Framework that block the Thread, for example:

```
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This also blocks it and waits for a response, but how?

Comment: Can you synchronously query your data source to retrieve the messages?

Comment: No, I can only receive messages from 'ReceiveMessages'.

Comment: thread.join() may help, it blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates.

Comment: Just as a side note - it is usually the `On*` methods, like `OnUserNamesArrived`, that **raise** the events and not **handle** them. You've got the convention around the wrong way.

Comment: Are you working **with** or working **on** the library? Is it a third-party library or yours?

Comment: I work on the library the example above about the event-based way is just to show how I'd work.

Comment: ReceiveMessages is not an event. It is a Thread-Method. 'Thread thread = new Thread(() => ReceiveMessages());' like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider one of the implementations of [`System.Threading.WaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx).

I often use `AutoResetEvent` for cross thread notifications that require blocking.

> AutoResetEvent allows threads to communicate with each other by
>   signaling. Typically, you use this class when threads need exclusive
>   access to a resource.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You will often hear this construct called a *semaphore* due to the signalling nature. WaitHandles are an OS feature so be make sure you dispose of the handle correctly.

The significant feature of `WaitHandle` is the `WaitOne` method.

> WaitOneBlocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal.

Comment: I put '_resetEvent.WaitOne()' in my 'GetsUserNames'-Method and '_resetEvent.Set()' in my 'ReceivedMessages'-Method, it worked!

Comment: @Berntonline glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the async and await properties of .NET framework. You'll need to set the `ReceiveMessages()` method as an async task and make the main thread which runs that method `ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetUserNames()` wait for the `ReceiveMessages()` to finish... I think it will work.

```
public async ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetUserNames()
{
    // Request userNames from server
    List<UserNames> userNameList = await ReceiveMessages();
    // return userNames
}

// Running on seperate thread, gets messages that server sents to client
async Task<List<UserNames>> ReceiveMessages()
{
    // Looks what message contains
    // Gets collection of userNames when requested (Working)
    // Triggers event 'UserNamesArrived' with userNames as argument
}
```

Take a look at that example: [await and async example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async)

Comment: 'ReceiveMessages' is already running on a seperate thread, I process all messages (not only userNames) that are received there. It's running in a while loop.

Comment: I understand, setting the method ReceiveMessages() as an async Task which returns a list of usernames and make it await inside the GetUserNames() methods. I update my post to show you the code...

Comment: The problem is I can't just call the method, because my seperate Thread already does that and gets the message. In addition, it is in a while loop.